# How do you reference a cell containing a date in a Query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a table to keep track of hours put in working on an Interior Design project. The table looks something like this:

```
8/16/2015   6:30:00 PM     8:00:00 PM    1.50   Floorplan
8/19/2015   10:00:00 AM    10:30:00 AM   0.50   Layout
8/19/2015   12:00:00 PM    3:30:00 PM    3.50   staircase
```

In another table, I want to consolidate all the dates into a single row that sums up the total amount of hours worked that day and concatenates the descriptions of what was worked on. So I'd like something like this:

```
    8/16/2015   1.50    Floorplan
    8/19/2015   4.00    Layout, staircase
```

The first part of making this happen, is writing a Query that could group the dates. This wasn't too difficult and I made it happen with

```
=QUERY(A2:E4, "select A, sum(D) group by A")
```

However, since I want to add the concatenated descriptions in the next cell, I've been trying to write a separate query for those cells. However I'm having a major issue, because I'm trying to look at the date on each row but I **can't reference the cell from inside the query.** So for example, I'm trying to insert this function:

```
=JOIN(", ", TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE((QUERY(A2:F4, "select E where day(B) = day(A6)))))
```

This function should get all the unique descriptions corresponding to a particular day (for simplicity ignoring the year and month), and join them up into a single cell. However it is failing because `day(A6)` is returning nothing even though there is a date in `A6` from the previous query.

So the question is, **how do I properly use a reference to another cell in a Google Sheets query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, one cannot put things like "A6" inside the query string because then it would just a part of a string, not a cell reference. Instead, concatenate the **value** of the cell to the string:

```
=JOIN(", ", UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:F4, "select E where day(A) ="&day(A6))))
```

You don't need `transpose`, because `join` works equally well with one-dimensional arrays of either direction: vertical or horizontal.

---

That said, I find a solution using `filter` slightly more readable:

```
=join(", ", unique(filter(E$2:E$4, A$2:A$4 = A6)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what the `&` in `&day(A6)` is for, and what the `$` in `A$2:A$4` is for?

Comment: & is concatenation of strings, e.g., "Java" & "Script" -> "JavaScript". The dollar signs are used for absolute cell references -  this is a common feature of all spreadsheet software; see, e.g., http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/14.3